# Is sys 'temporarily' imported when print is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, sys

I was looking at the Python documentation for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) which states:

> print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

As it can be seen, if the `file` on which to print is not specified, the default `sys.stdout` is used, which got me thinking.

Calling `print` definitely **does not import** `sys` in the background, so how does it work?

is `sys.stdout` somehow *reachable* from everywhere?

---

**Example:**

I am using PyCharm and I want to create a function that either prints a message `text` to a file or to standard output. I began writing:

```
def my_print(text, file=None):
    print(text, file=file if file is not None else ?)
```

So what goes after `else`? `sys.stdout` does not work and obviously, I am **not interested** in the verbose:

```
def my_print(text, file=None):
    if file is None:
        print(text)
    else:
        print(text, file=file)
```

Comment: No, neither of those things. That default is in the *definition* of print, not in the place where you use it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for the quick comment. Could you elaborate a bit on that? Maybe with an answer even?

Answer (score 1):

The other answer points out that print is implemented in C. However, *even if* it was implemented in Python, that would not mean that `sys` was available from everywhere.

Consider this code:

utils.py

```
import sys

def my_print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False):
    file.write(sep.join(objects))
```

main.py

```
from utils import print

my_print('foo')
```

Here `sys` is only available within utils, but print will still output to `sys.stdout` without it being accessible from main.

Comment: so on the `utils.py` the `import sys` **must** be there.

Comment: Further, it is even possible (but unlikely) to implement as `def my_print(text): import sys; sys.stdout...` where `sys` will not exist anywhere outside of the local scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think @DanielRoseman gave a good idea of *why* the implementation might not necessarily give you access to `sys` directly, but to address the last part of your question, you can use this approach...:

```
def my_print(text, file=None):
    print(text, **({'file': file} if file else {}))
```

... where basically you are unpacking the argument `file=file` if `file` is present, otherwise pass no argument.

In terms of readability I think your original implementation is superior however.

---

Actually you can just pass `None`:

```
def my_print(text, file=None):
    print(text, file=file)
```

... and it would just `print` the `text` if `file` is not provided...